# Build failure - Restore package option not working in Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online)

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-process, azure-devops

I am using a TFS Git project in Team Services and while my project compiles locally, I get a build failure when I check in my code to VS online and manually queue the build.

The errors at the moment are only pertaining to enterprise library data access dlls. I am using V6 of the library and this is error I get

> The type or namespace name 'Practices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

In my build definition I have checked the box against both Restore Nuget Packages and when that alone did not work, I checked the box against [Clean] as well. I still get that error. My packages.config files are checked in for each of the projects in the solution. I also have the Packages folder checked in but this folder has no dlls. It only has the various `.nupkg` files and respective `.xml` files checked in. Is this causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to either checkin the DLLs or delete the nupkg files.  The build server thinks you already have the packages so its not trying to restore them but the DLLs aren't there to reference.

Comment: what if I delete the entire packages folder?

Comment: Look through the build logs and find where it is restoring Nuget packages.  Is there any further information here that might be helpful?  Also are you sure you have a Nuget package referenced for this particular DLL?

Comment: I fixed it. Actually I had turned off restore nuget packages in the build during earlier attempts at fixing it and that had not been turned back on.